# what is the correct syntax for this

Tags: hibernate, spring

```
        <bean id="ssoSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:sso-hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="configurationClass">
                <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
            </property>
this is the part im unsure of....   
<property name="configfile">
                <value>classpath:sso-hibernate.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

i know there are at least a half dozen ways to do this, but for my needs this would be easiest.  whats the syntax for the property that would specify which hibernate.properties file to use?  reason being this app may end up having about 5 or 6 simultaneous db connections and they have to be in different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [the hibernateProperties property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setHibernateProperties%28java.util.Properties%29), which lets you set a Properties instance in the factory bean. Thanks to the magic of Spring PropertyEditors, you can just write

```
<property name="hibernateProperties" value="classpath:sso-hibernate.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is a good example of a using hibernet.properties at [answer on coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/60666/oa/define-Hibernate-SessionFactory-Spring-applicationcontext)

This is the bean that is declared

```
<bean id="hibernateConfigProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="location"> 
       <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```